# Change the appearance of the file browser?

Tags: nautilus, themes

How can I change the appearance of the file browser?

I want my file browser look like:

[image: Screenshot of file browser in another theme]

My current file browser looks like:

[image: Screenshot of my file browser]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [**Nautilus-Elementary**](http://ammonkey.posterous.com/nautilus-elementary-project-reactivated-jupit), You can get it using theses commands in a terminal :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

See [OMG! UBUNTU! Post!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/phew-nautilus-elementary-revived-in-time-for-ubuntu-natty/)

Also You don't want to miss the `gloobus-preview` !! (A quick look, simply hit space for any file or folder and it will open like this):

[image]

**Install:**

`sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I missing the boat on this one, but from what I am able to discern, you would simply want to hit <kbd>F9</kbd> while in Nautilus to activate the side panel and then select `Icon View` as denoted in the image below.

[image]